# Run Tree Structure in Python

Tags: python

I implemented tree structure as follow:

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        ...

    def isBST(self, curr):
        ...

def main():
    one = TreeNode(1)
    two = TreeNode(2)
    three = TreeNode(3)
    two.left = one
    two.right = three
    Solution.isBST(self, two)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm not sure how to run it, it's giving me an error on `Solution.isBST(self, two)`, I guess it's because self is not defined.

However, if I do :

```
Solution.isBST(two)
```

It says the function is missing an argument. So I guess self must be called?.
If I do

```
self.isBST(two)
```

Then, I'm not sure where to reference self in the first place. Anyone knows how to run it?

Comment: What is the `self` in `main` anyway? You're calling it without any arguments here: `main()`

Comment: @ForceBru Hi, I just updated my question. I need to run and test my methods and I'm not sure how to do it. I was just trying if putting `self` in `main` would work.

Comment: You're on the right track: `isBST` is a method of the class `Solution`, so that class should be involved in calling the method. Take a look at some OOP tutorial, like this one: https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 1):

So, you need either to instantiate an object of class Solution `solution = Solution()` and then call it's methods: `solution.isBST(two)`, or you need to define `isBST` as a class method by removing `self` from its definition: `def isBST(curr):`. Then it is not needed to instantiate an object, and you can call class method directly: `Solution.isBST(two)`. The decision is based on your vision of program architecture.